# Only Run OpenRewrite on VCS changed files

Tags: java, openrewrite

Is there a way we can specify only files that are modified on local to be modified. Like in some IDEs we have make changes to only VCS changed files, is it possible to only run rewrite on VCS changed files

Answer (score 2):

In short: no. OpenRewrite needs to parse your whole project to correctly resolve types and apply recipes, and therefore we don't support only running against particular files. Then when apply recipes, we write out change to any files. We do support exclusions for certain file patterns, but that might be more trouble for you to set up for what it's worth.